# Return New Promise Using Static Function

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm looking for a fast way to return a promise with a fulfillment without needing to create a new promise.

Is there a static way of doing what I do at Point A (below)

```
new Promise(function(resolve){
    resolve(data1, data2);
})
.then(function(data1, data2){
    if(something){
        // returns promise
    }
    else{
        // POINT A
        return new Promise(function(fulfill){
            fulfill(data1, data2);
        });    
    }   
})
.then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Ideally something like `return Promise.fulfill(data1, data2);` which will save me from writing a function which calls a function.

Comment: Desired implementation of static function: `Promise.fulfill = function(data1, data2, ...){ return new Promise(function(fulfill){ fulfill(data1, data2, ...); } ); }`

Comment: Just saying, inside a `then` callback you don't need to create promises at all, you can simply `return` any plain value as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`Promise.resolve(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

> The `Promise.resolve(value)` method returns a Promise object that is resolved with the given value. If the value is a thenable (i.e. has a then method), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state; otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value.

You can always only pass a single value btw (your example wouldn't work).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll check that out. However, upon construction, you can pass multiple parameters so why isn't a faster static method possible.

Comment: *"However, upon construction, you can pass multiple parameters"* No, you can't. `resolve` only takes one argument as well. A promise represents a *single* future value. Of course that value could be an array.

Comment: Oos you're correct, thank you very much, I'll resort to using an array/object.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `return Promise.resolve(x)` inside a `.then` function. It's implicit. Just `return x`!